# Did Nicole de Boer appear as any other Star Trek character prior to her role as Ezri Dax?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I seem to remember Nicole de Boer in a science fiction television program prior to her role as Ezri Dax in Star Trek: Deep Space Nine, but I can't think of what that role was or what program she was in.  Maybe I am confusing her with Lexa Doig, who was in Andromeda and in Stargate SG1.  Did Nicole play another character in any Star Trek series prior to her role as Ezri Dax?

Comment: The Stargate series that she was in was Atlantis, not SG-1

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Lexa Doig played Dr. Carolyn Lam in Stargate SG1 and she played Andromeda Ascendant in Andromeda.  But the Dr. Carolyn Lam character does not appear in Stargate Atlantis.  Nicole de Boer played Dr. Alison Porter in Stargate Atlantis but she did not appear in SG1, as you said.  Nicole de Boer played Ezri Dax in Startrek DS9 and Cadet Bree Tristan in The Outer Limits: The Quality of Mercy.  Now I think I have it clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a 1995 episode of The Outer Limits she plays a character who is part of the Terran space force at war with an alien species, which is a bit like DS9 in the Dominion War. That episode is called "Quality of Mercy." Might that be it?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Nicole de Boer is not credited with any other role in Star Trek - but she was in a few scifi/fantasy shows as a guest actor before Deep Space Nine, including TekWar - which was written by and starred William Shatner:

https://m.imdb.com/name/nm0207498/filmotype/actress?ref_=m_nmfm_1

Comment: @HorusKol I see that Lexa Doig is in TekWar too.  Thank you for pointing out this series.  I had not heard of it before now.